# Angular - using orderBy in ng-repeat to order in increasing order

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have a JSON this way:

```
"db" : {
    "x" : {
        "0" : "A",
        "1" : "B",
        "2" : "C",
        "3" : "D",
        "4" : "E",
        "5" : "F",
        "6" : "G",
        "7" : "H",
        "8" : "I",
        "9" : "J",
        "10" : "K",
        "11" : "L",
        "12" : "M",
        "13" : "N"
    }
```

In the controller I have:

```
$scope.object = currentObject.get();
$scope.x = $scope.object.db.x;
```

(currentObject.get() is a function I made to take data from the DB, and in the DB there the JSON I've written before)

And in the view:

```
<div ng-repeat="y in x">{{y}}</div>
```

I expected the result to be this:

```
<div>A</div>
<div>B</div>
<div>C</div>
etc. etc.
```

Instead what I see is that:

```
<div>A</div>
<div>K</div>
<div>L</div>
<div>M</div>
<div>N</div>
<div>B</div>
etc. etc.
```

How to fix this with orderBy in ng-repeat?

Comment: can't order an object in javascript. Use array instead

Comment: So, have I to create an array with the same components of the JSON object? Really there isn't any alternative?

Comment: However I tried with array and it worked. For the moment, thank you :)

Comment: You could map it to array after you receive it but most data sets come in arrays and angular works best with arrays

Comment: Why would you *not* make `x` an array given that its properties all have numeric key names with no skipped values?

Comment: Because I think it's "waste" to create an array if I have a JSON with the same information. However if this is the only way to do that there's nothing to do...

Comment: The real question is why is your data stored like that in your db. You would normally have rows for each of them. When you fetch the data you would get back an array.

Comment: @MatteoDiSabatino I think you are misunderstanding, set the server up to deliver the data as array. If you do need it as a dictionary it can easily be mapped to an array in just a few lines when you receive it though

Comment: @WayneEllery I wanted the data to be stored as in an array.

Comment: @chalietfl I think you gotta reason, I'll try. If I'll have problems I'll use the solution here below :).

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet to add to @charlietfl's response, but here is an open issue regarding ngRepeat's support for ordering by an object's key: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/8458

An array is the way to go for sure unless the keys in your data are IDs of the values. You still need an array, but your data could look something like this;

```
var x = [
    { id: 0, value: 'A' },
    { id: 1, value: 'B' },
    { id: 2, value: 'C' },
    etc...
]
```

and you could use:

```
<div ng-repeat="obj in x | orderBy: 'id'">{{ obj.value }}</div>
```

Comment: You can also make a custom filter to turn an object into an array on the fly in the expression/template.

Comment: Ah I left that part out. Yes. Many suggest a `toArray` filter to map the object to an array. The suggestion is actually in the issue link as well.